# OPTIONS request fail when posting to a standalone server

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, grafana

I am trying to create dashboard on my local Grafana server using APIs.

When testing with Postman, everything goes fine and my POST request did actually create new db. However, when going into javascript, a pre-flight OPTIONS request is sent ahead of POST, causing 404.

My question is, is there anyway to overcome this regarding that Grafana is a standalone server I download from an online source, and I cannot do anything to it's backend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide code, urls? Now it looks like you just use wrong url in JS code. Maybe it is simple misprint :-)

Comment: Hi @Sabik, I don't have anything wrong with the url, it's just grafana doesn't support options request handler so that requires server config.

What I am trying to do is not touching the server, and I was suggested to send request first to php and use curl to send it. However, no luck yet.